Opening new page after barcode detection with zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView throws COMException
I have a plain barcode reader app that tries to navigate to a new page with the search result, but I'm getting this weird COMException that I simply don't understand.
MainPage.xaml:
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.App.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.App"
             xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Maui.Controls;assembly=ZXing.Net.MAUI.Controls">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:BarcodeScannerBindingContext />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Padding="30,0"
        Spacing="25">
        <zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView
            x:Name="cameraBarcodeReaderView"
            BarcodesDetected="OnBarcodesDetected"
            IsDetecting="{Binding IsDetectingInternal}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsDetectingInternal}" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>

MainPage.xaml.cs:
private async void OnBarcodesDetected(object sender, BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Results.Count() > 0)
    {
        BindingContext.IsDetectingInternal = false;
        string barcode = e.Results[0].Value;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ResultsPage(barcode)); //Throws COMException
    }
}

Stack trace:

   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.g__Throw|39_0(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ICommandBarMethods.get_PrimaryCommands(IObjectReference _obj)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.CommandBar.get_PrimaryCommands()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Toolbar.UpdateMenu()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Toolbar.MapToolbarItems(IToolbarHandler arg1, Toolbar arg2)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapperExtensions.c__DisplayClass2_0`2.b__0(TViewHandler h, TVirtualView v, Action`2 p)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapperExtensions.c__DisplayClass1_0`2.g__newMethod|0(IElementHandler handler, IElement view)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper`2.c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0(IElementHandler h, IElement v)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdatePropertyCore(String key, IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView)
   at Microsoft.Maui.PropertyMapper.UpdateProperty(IElementHandler viewHandler, IElement virtualView, String property)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ElementHandler.UpdateValue(String property)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Toolbar.SetProperty[T](T& backingStore, T value, String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Toolbar.set_ToolbarItems(IEnumerable`1 value)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NavigationPageToolbar.ApplyChanges(NavigationPage navigationPage)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NavigationPageToolbar.NavigationPageChildrenChanged(Object s, ElementEventArgs a)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.OnChildAdded(Element child)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.OnChildAdded(Element child)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.InsertLogicalChild(Int32 index, Element element)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Page.InternalChildrenOnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NavigationPage.PushPage(Page page)
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NavigationPage.MauiNavigationImpl.c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0()
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.NavigationPage.d__100.MoveNext()
   at MyApp.App.MainPage.d__3.MoveNext() in MyApp\\MyApp.App\\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 45

P.S.: Code for BarcodeScannerBindingContext taken from here
The question: Do I need to turn off the scanner and if so, how?

From the StackTrace  you shared above, I couldn't find the relative log about the COMException, could you please post the full log about this problem?

@JessieZhang-MSFT That is the full stack. It comes out as COMException in Visual Studio. What full log are you talking about please?

What full log are you talking about please? What I meant before was the full stack.  It comes out as COMException in Visual Studio.  Could you please post a screenshot of this exception?

@MPelletier is this a windows exception or does it occur on all platforms? If you comment out the navigation line in the handler, is there still an exception? Even though the issue comes up as COMException it might be worthwhile to rule out a threading problem by inspecting the the boolean value of App.Current.MainPage.Dispatcher?.IsDispatchRequired in the handler.

@JessieZhang-MSFT I figured out the cause. It's a threading issue. It's not about the scanner per se, it's the async event handler. I'll work from there and find a fix. Thanks for your insight.

@IV. Same, Threading issue. Thanks for your insight

So, it was a threading issue. What resolved it (Thanks to @IV.'s input):
private void OnBarcodesDetected(object sender, BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Results.Count() > 0)
    {
        BindingContext.IsDetectingInternal = false;
        string barcode = e.Results[0].Value;
 
        Action action = () => {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new ResultsPage(barcode));
        };

        App.Current.Mainpage.Dispatcher?.DispatchAsync(action);
    }
}

